# PHP: sending a link to a results page

Tags: php, html

I am learning PHP:

A person will get a results page. I want to enable this person to be able to send the results page (via link) to their given email (form).  The link won't be constant as the results page would be specific for that person/ possibly session?

The results page is simply a html script containing sequences that have been run through a prediction model.

Comment: What exacly is "the results page"?

Comment: You need to add more information to your question otherwise it's too broad to be answered in a useful manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to have the search terms in the URL itself.

For instance, if its one search term, it could very easily be:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/search.php?term=search+term
```

Just handle this in PHP as:

```
<?php
$term = $_GET['term'];
/* blah blah, process the search and echo results */
?>
```

You could even utilize paging, and put the page in the URL itself, so that when the person returns to the link, it brings them right back to where they emailed it from. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Store the results in a database.  Construct a php page that would fetch that data from the database according to a GET variable. Give a link with appropriate GET variables to the user.